# Code Management using Endevor

Tags: mainframe, endevor

I am new to Endevor. I want to learn the Code Manmagement using it.
Could you please provide me the link of Study Material for the same?

Regards,
Manasi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CA Endevor is a large and complex product to master.

Access to CA (Computer Associates) product documentation is provided from [this page](https://support.ca.com/irj/portal/anonymous?NavigationTarget=navurl://ee60822d8a58513f97e5da6c23498494)
but requires registration to log-in.  I did not attempt to register so have not gained further access to their documentation from this site.

The shop I work in uses Endevor and, as many customers do, has download several 
CA Guides and Tutorials to our LAN. The documentation is extensive and takes some patience to navigate.

Your systems administrator should be able to provide links to or copies of relevant documentation if Endevor has been installed at your site.

I found the following documents "floating" around but they provide a very limited view of the product: 
[Getting Started - Installing and configuring](http://middleware.its.state.nc.us/middleware/Documentation/Endeavor/F001612E.pdf)
and [User Guide](http://middleware.its.state.nc.us/middleware/CICS/Documentation/Endevor70/F001841E.pdf).

Sorry, I cannot be any more helpful than this!

Answer (score 0):

Endevor is a tool for which primarily is used for source control with features to hook in to change management, release management and configuration management systems. For start have a read through SCM theory and related topics.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endevor

Every tool has its own take on how theory is applied. There is no one true way. 
Once you understand the basics of SCM then learn how Endevor implements SCM and how your shop has configured Endevor.

At the heart of Endevor is the environment, system and type configurations and SCL which is the language used to execute Endevor functions. Your system administrators should have a map of the defined Endevor environments for your [SDLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Development_Life_Cycle) showing DEV TEST PROD etc.

The Endevor user guide will help you get started. Much of what you really need to actually use Endevor will be dependant on how Endevor is customised at your shop. Your local Endevor administrators should have documentation to get help you started and visualise the system configuration. You can also find this documentation via google. E.g. The SCL manaual is ftp://ftp.ca.com/caproducts/endevor/workstation/ews80/docs/ews80scl.pdf or search google for ews80scl.pdf

Your Endevor system should have SMPLTEST and SMPLPROD environments defined which you can use to learn how Endevor works. Your local system documentation will show you how to access Endevor via ISPF and submit Endevor batch jobs.

Pro Tip: An action submitted from the Endevor [ISPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISPF) interface generally submits a batch job. Go to [SDSF](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/features/sdsf/) and view the [JCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Control_Language) of Endevor jobs to learn what Endevor is doing when elements are added, updated, deleted, moved, checked in, checked out, etc.

The Endevor Quick-Edit option makes using Endevor via ISPF a lot easier, as does RDz ([Rational Developer for System z](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/rtnv1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.rdz/rdz/7.6z/Endevorintegration.html)) which provides a workstation client side view of Endevor allowing you to use Endevor without logging on to the mainframe.